# Code logic to store nested hash map in SQL table

Tags: java, spring-boot, hashmap

I have a function which fetches the table rows in form of nested hash map: Map<String,Map<String,List<Map<String,String>>>.
Now i need to store the same data to another SQL table. How can I do that?

Comment: Not enough details. Do you want to populate some table from nested map or you need to store the entire map in a column? What kind of database do you use?

Comment: I have a SQL table and the rows are fetched in the form of nested hashmap. I created a new table which is a copy of the previous table and have to insert the same rows fetched before In to the new table. Since the data is hashmap, how can I store it in the SQL table